# Git Pull, One developer only on project only, local repo pull after every push required?

Tags: git, fetch, pull

I have a very simple question that many in this forum may have treaded upon. 
I regularly push my code to remote repo and my question is that everytime I do a push to remote repo do i need to follow it up with a `git pull --all` or `git fetch --all` for my local repo to be sync'd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is NO, if there is only one developer, the head of your local branch is same as the remote branch. Because of that it is not required to sync with the remote and you can push your code directly.

Comment: @ Hiran. I had a practice of not doing it but I keep getting a message that my branch is ahead by x commits. Just wondering why?

Comment: Best practice is to take a pull before pushing anything to remote, anyway that message is normally occurs when your remote has been updated by someone else. Are you the only one who works on that repository? When you do it is there any other commits pulled from the repository?

Comment: @newb7777 It means that your branch has x more commits than the remote. Pushing refers to sending these commits to the remote.

Answer (score 0):

it's a nice habit to have to pull after each push, but it is not required if only one dev is working on the repository.